# What would all of the conditions involved in an ocean of ketchup be?

Tags: ocean

My world has an ocean that's made of ketchup. The freshwater lakes and rivers are also ketchup, too. How do I have creatures swim in it, plants grow in it, and what about the tides and waves?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! Currently, this is too broad, as it's asking three different questions - "How could a creature swim in ketchup", "how could a plant grow in ketchup", and "what would the tides/waves be like in an ocean of ketchup". Each of those should be asked as a separate question - and you'd probably need to provide additional information for each (by "creatures", do you mean fish? The tides are controlled by the moon, so how many moons does your planet have?)

Comment: You might want to start with a "How to explain ketchup in place of water?" but maybe this is handwavium. It helps to explain the ecology if we understand the origin. It's an evolution thing.

Comment: How does the ketchup flow around?

Comment: Some other questions that come to mind: Are there tides? How does precipitation work? Can any sea creatures see through the ketchup? Would land animals evolve vision differently due to this? Do animals and plants filter out parts of the ketchup and then work like we do, or are thier fluids ketchup-based? Does the ketchup spoil and get replenished? Can animals get by on just ketchup and no other food? Which came first the tomato or the ketchup?

Comment: I disagree that you need to explain the ketchup. Sometimes we get caught up in the backstory and forget to let you set the rules for your own world. I think this question could be kept open if you ask just one question at a time. Perhaps, given a lake of ketchup, is it possible for plant life to thrive in it? Another question would then ask about fish. A third question would ask about tides in a viscous sea. I don't believe you're asking an unreasonable question (But: (a) ketchup is organic, unlike water, so it will rot IRL, does it on your world? And (b) what about precipitation?)

Comment: Your biggest problem is going to be the vinegar in the ketchup. Vinegar is very acidic, not at all conducive to life.

Comment: An ocean of PH 3.9 acidic, rancid, tomato byproduct.  Yummy

Comment: Ketchup, left to itself, will gradually separate into vinegar and tomato paste. Lakes of vinegar on top of lakebed of paste. Vinegar is a solution of water and acetic acid, and they can be separated by ordinary sun-powered distillation, perhaps leading to some unexpected results